# NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Right now I'm trying to write a function to moving up frame when keyboard appears on the screen.
I started to use NSNNotificationCenter. My code is working but not correctly. When keyboard appears my formView is moving up but when I start to edit next textField in formView, formView is moving up again. What's wrong with my code? 
Thanks.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGRect frame = self.formView.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= 170;

    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;

    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    formView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: You should NOT hard code 170 in this code. You should read the documentation, and it will tell you how you can get the real size of the keyboard. On iOS 5 with an iPad, the keyboard can be split, so you should not adjust your frame. That's just one example. Never hard code stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add again your 170 pixels (or whatever you calculate as suggested by Mike) to the `origin.y` of your view when the keyboard is disappearing. When you click on another text field, technically the current keyboard will disappear (your view does not react in any way) and a new keyboard will appear (your `keyboardWillShow` will be called again and you shift your view again up by 170 px).